# Is there any way to enumerate all the known hostnames for a server in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dns

I have a chunk of code like:

```
http.Server(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(0, function() {
    port = server.address().port;
    console.log("server listening on: " + port);
});
```

This works great for getting the port, but I want to print out each possible DNS name that the server is listening on, too (so localhost:8080, foo.com:8080, etc).

I've tried some of the obvious things (like `dns.reverse('0.0.0.0')`) and no luck so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for a server to get a list of all its DNS names -- I could create a new DNS entry for 0.0.0.0 as www.foo.com right now (assuming I owned the foo.com domain, but I wouldn't need to own 0.0.0.0), and 0.0.0.0 would never know about it (unless and until it started to receive http connections with the Host: header set to www.foo.com).

Comment: Sure, any client can refer to a host however it wants. But surely the host has some idea of the names it expects, too. And if the hostnames aren't possible, I'd settle for a list of IP addresses the system is listening on.